# Backbone collection find by id

Tags: backbone.js

this.id is undefined in Blog.Collections.Posts class. What's wrong?

Blog collection

```
Blog.Collections.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: Blog.Models.Post,
  url: function() {
    console.log(this.id);
    if (this.id) {
      return '/api/posts/'+this.id
    }
    else{
      return '/api/posts'
    }
  }

});
```

My router:

```
Blog.Routers.Posts = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
    ""                  :        "index",
    "entry/:id" :        "show"
  },

  show: function(id) {
    var collection = new Blog.Collections.Posts({id: id});
    collection.fetch({
      success: function() {
        var view = new Blog.Views.PostsIndex({ collection: collection });
        console.log(collection);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections don't have an id by default. Unless you're explicitly assigning an id to your collection, `this.id` becomes undefined. IDs are standard attribute of models. What you want to do is simply:

```
// Collection URL
url: function() {
    return '/api/posts'
}
```

Backbone models, if they are a part of a collection will use the collection `url` when fetching and saving. Thus, if you do something like this:

```
// myModel is a part of the collection
myModel.save();
```

It will automatically goto:

```
'/api/posts/:id'  // Assuming your model already has a model.id
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

IMO your code is wrong by design. You can get an idea from [here](https://github.com/thikonom/django-backbone-blog) (go to `blog/static/js/app.js`) on how you can organize a blogging app on backbone.